# Why does inner_join behave differently for data.table?

Tags: r, inner-join, data.table, dplyr

I wanted to join a data frame with a data table using `dplyr` function `inner_join()`. Here are my codes.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

DF <- data.frame(x = rep( c("a","b","c"), each=3), 
                 y = rep( c(1,3,6), 3))

DT <- data.table(x = rep( c("a","b","c"), each=3), 
                 y = rep( c(1,3,6), 3))

W <- data.frame(x = c("b","c","d"), 
              foo = c(4,2,9))
```

When I try to join two data frames, `inner_join()` works as expected.

```
inner_join(DF,W)

Joining by: "x"
  x y foo
1 b 1   4
2 b 3   4
3 b 6   4
4 c 1   2
5 c 3   2
6 c 6   2
```

But when I try to join data frame with a data table, `inner_join()` gives unexpected result.

```
inner_join(DT,W)

Joining by: "x"
  x y foo
1 b 1   2
2 b 3   2
3 b 6   2
4 c 1   9
5 c 3   9
6 c 6   9
```

Could anyone please give me some hints why this is happening? Thanks in advance for your time.

**Note:** I am using RStudio Version 0.98.1056 on MAC Maverick OS X 10.9.4 and the `sessionInfo()` is

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.2        data.table_1.9.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] assertthat_0.1 parallel_3.1.1 plyr_1.8.1     Rcpp_0.11.2    reshape2_1.4  
[6] stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: That's because of a bug in `data.table` that results in wrong result when merging `character` class with `factor` class. Try changing `DT` to `DT <- data.table(x = factor(rep( c("a","b","c"), each=3)), y = rep( c(1,3,6), 3))` and then try `inner_join(DT,W)` again

Comment: Just to be clear, while @DavidArenburg's comment is (partly) true in that when `x`'s key column is a factor and corresponding `i`'s column is character, `x[i]` returns incorrect result (which is a bug in data.table), it's a **red herring** and has nothing to do with your example. Rather it's due to a bug in `dplyr`, that has since then been fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What David mentions about a [bug in `data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/499)  between factor and character columns is true, and it's still not fixed. But unfortunately it's a **Red Herring** and is **not** the source of your troubles.

However, the reason for this is because there's no `inner_join.data.table` method in `dplyr v0.2`, and therefore it calls the `inner_join.data.frame` method (since a `data.table` is also a `data.frame`).

```
require(dplyr) ## 0.2 CRAN
require(data.table) ## 1.9.2

methods(inner_join)
# [1] inner_join.data.frame* inner_join.tbl_df*     inner_join.tbl_dt*    
# [4] inner_join.tbl_sql*
```

And therefore, when you do:

```
inner_join(DF, W)
```

or

```
inner_join(DT, W)
```

both call the same `dplyr's` internal join implementation.

The reason it gives different result is because `DF` and `W` both have `x` as factor and `DT` has `x` as a character column.

You can reproduce this bug by changing `DF$x` to character type:

```
DF$x = as.character(DF$x)
inner_join(DF, W)
# Joining by: "x"
#   x y foo
# 1 b 1   2
# 2 b 3   2
# 3 b 6   2
# 4 c 1   9
# 5 c 3   9
# 6 c 6   9
```

But this seems to have been fixed in the development version of `dplyr`.

Comment: Thanks @Arun for nice explanation. It really helped me understand the comment made by @David. My understanding about `data.table` is that it is also a `data.frame`. Now, if `data.frame` reads text as factor by default, should not `data.table` do the same by default? Or is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: David's comment is not relevant to your problem. Please read the answer *again*.

Comment: David's suggestion gave a solution of my problem. I agree what his first comment indicates may not be source of my problem.

Comment: This appears to be fixed in the dev version (at least there's now a method for `inner_join.data.table`).